# Realistic / Optimistic duration to Knockdown Ceiling

Tags: ceiling

I am interested in apply knockdown to 3BR/2BA apartment.  If two newbies watch a youTube video (regarding Knockdown).  How long will it take to do 1300 square feet?  One newbie has an engineering background and the other is also handy with tools.

Comment: Knockdown is a little more complicated than say orange peel, or even popcorn. It may take you a day+ per room if 2 people are doing it. Engineering background or not, this is a learned skill. I personally would suggest you practice on scrap pieces flat, on a pair of saw horses. If you can master the technic, then move on to trying on scrap pieces standing up vertical like a wall. Once you have gotten it down move on to real walls. As far as tools, a basic set of drywall knives in several sizes.

Comment: Excellent idea: I have a large scrap of drywall to practice upon